# Sequential output of files in python

Tags: python

I wanted a method that would enable me to output files sequentially to a folder and give them a name that is stored in an array.

Here is the layout of the data:

```
16837,144335,LOC516870
141961,198534,LOC100337147
223927,257577,LOC100849016
267259,273010,LOC512435
269335,277567,LOC100300061
```

I have read it in using:

```
from numpy import *
x,y=genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\Mohammed\\Desktop\\positions1.txt', dtype=None, delimiter=',', usecols=[0,1],unpack=True)
z=genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\Mohammed\\Desktop\\positions1.txt', dtype='|S12', delimiter=',', usecols=[2],unpack=True)
exit
```

Now I want to construct a do loop that names the files with the variable z sequentially as

```
LOC516870.txt 
LOC100337147.txt
```

and so on.

I tried the following:

```
for i in range (6):

 f = open("C:\\Users\\Mohammed\\Desktop\\Sequences\\'z'.txt", 'wt')

f.write(Seq)

f.close()
```

While I know a similar code would work in Perl, it didn't work in python and it says that its an invalid syntax!

Your help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide the error message.

Comment: You need at least to learn about: [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html#format-examples), [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), and learnign about [`with open() as`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) wouldn't hurt. *Nobody here on SO will write the code for you.*

Answer (score 2):

Assuming python 2.7:

```
f = open("C:\Users\Mohammed\Desktop\Sequences\%s.txt" % z, 'wt')
```

where z is your variable that you want to use as the name and changes as you go through the loop.

For python 3:

```
f = open("C:\Users\Mohammed\Desktop\Sequences\{0}.txt".format(z), 'wt')
```

Comment: Thank you yokuyuki. I tried to use your code and it doesn't work maybe because I have python  2.6. unfortunately I have to still keep it since numpy is not supported in windows for later versions and I am using numpy to import the variable z as you can see and since I am new to python I still can't find a better way to import it into an array that directly. I will keep playing with your code to see if it would work. Thank you!

Comment: I think I get it: The problem is that python is looking for the files LOC516870.txt, LOC100337147.txt etc when they don't actually exist: it outputs the following message: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\\Users\\Mohammed\\Desktop\\Sequences\\['LOC516870' 'LOC100337147' 'LOC100849016'].txt ,,,which is true since I want to create all those files! I don't know if there is a way to create them anew in python!?

Comment: I got it: this code does the trick!:                                for i in range (806):
f = open('C:\Users\Mohammed\Desktop\Sequences\%s.txt' % (z[i]), 'wt')